# How can I convert PascalCase string to a usable slug in Laravel 7 with PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, string-formatting, helper, laravel-7

I currently have a variable with the value of `"ExtraOption"`. I wonder if it is possible (with Laravel helpers perhaps) convert this string into a usable slug. For example: `"extra-option"`.

Can anyone help me out with a single, clean solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**`Str::kebab()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-kebab-case) method to converts the given string to kebab-case:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$converted = Str::kebab('ExtraOption');

// extra-option
```

Laravel 7 has new feature [**Fluent String Operations**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#fluent-strings) which provides a variety of helpful string manipulation functions.

#### `kebab`

The kebab method converts the given string to kebab-case:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$converted = Str::of('ExtraOption')->kebab();

// extra-option
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

...
Str::slug(implode(' ', preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'camelCaseToSlug')))
> camel-case-to-slug
...
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Why downvote? This answer is not wrong and can be an alternative.

Comment: The Laravel kebab function seems to work, while the slug function plainly ignores the capitals used. The docs provide no answer about whether this will stay like this in the future. This answer provides a future-proof solution. Perhaps an alternative could be: `strtolower(implode("-", preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'camelCaseToSlug')))`